# How to use 'IloOplOutputFile' in Cplex to write variables with more than one index?

Tags: optimization, indexing, cplex, ilog, opl

I am trying to write the result data to an external file because of an error I got after running the code for 16 hours.

I found the code above, it works for the variables with one index but my variables are not with one index. There are even variables with 4 indexes. How can I adapt this code to my situation?

```
execute{
  var ofile = new IloOplOutputFile("modelRun.txt");
  ofile.writeln("Data:");
  for(var i in thisOplModel.r){
     ofile.writeln("d["+i+"+"]="+thisOplModel.d[i]]);
  }
  ofile.writeln("Optimal objective value="+cplex.getObjValue());
  ofile.writeln("Optimal variable values:");
  for(i in thisOplModel.r){
     ofile.writeln("x["+i+"]="+thisOplModel.x[i]);
  }
  ofile.close();
}
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If x is a 4D array instead of:

```
for(i in thisOplModel.r){
     ofile.writeln("x["+i+"]="+thisOplModel.x[i]);
  }
```

you could directly write:

```
ofile.writeln("x="+thisOplModel.x);
```

Comment: Thank you, it is actually exactly what i wanted but I'd like to also learn what will the outcome be.   

For 1D and 2D arrays in notepad it gives the arrays like: 
y = [3 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 4 3 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 2 0 0];
d = [[1 1 0 0 1 0]
       [0 1 0 0 1 0]
       [0 1 0 0 1 0]]

I am not sure how a 4D array would be in notepad.

Answer (score 0):

About displaying 4D arrays:

```
range r=1..2;
int x[i in r][j in r][k in r][l in r]=i+j+k+l;

execute
{
writeln("x=",x);
}
```

which gives

```
x= [[[[4 5]
                 [5 6]]
             [[5 6]
                 [6 7]]]
         [[[5 6]
                 [6 7]]
             [[6 7]
                 [7 8]]]]
```